# How to handle login failure with Spring API on server and Retrofit2 on Android?

Tags: spring, api, kotlin, retrofit

On server side I have created simple Spring API with authentication. I have just added `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")` dependency and when I go to url with browser - it shows login page when I'm not logged in.

For now I'm using basic authentication, my username and password set in configuration file like this (resources/application.properties file):

```
spring.security.user.name=myusername
spring.security.user.password=mypassword
spring.security.user.roles=manager
```

I'm also using [Spring Data REST](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest), so Spring creates API automatically for JPA repositories that exist in my project. I had to  set up my database, create JPA repositories for tables and add `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")` to my dependencies to make it work.

On Android side I call my API with this Adapter and Client.

```
interface ApiClient {
    @GET("inventoryItems/1")
    suspend fun getFirstInventoryItem(): Response<InventoryItemDto>
}

object ApiAdapter {

    private const val API_BASE_URL = "http://some.url/"
    private const val API_USERNAME = "myusername"
    private const val API_PASSWORD = "mypassword"

    val apiClient: ApiClient = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
        .client(getHttpClient(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD))
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiClient::class.java)

    private fun getHttpClient(user: String, pass: String): OkHttpClient = 
        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .authenticator(getBasicAuth(user,pass))
            .build()

    private fun getBasicAuth(username: String?, password: String?): Authenticator? =
        object : Authenticator {
            override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: okhttp3.Response): Request? {
                return response
                    .request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password))
                    .build()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call my API on Android:
(I'm calling this from onViewCreated on my view Fragment)

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val item: InventoryItemDto? = ApiAdapter.apiClient.getFirstInventoryItem().body()
    binding?.tvTest?.text = item.toString()
}
```

---

When I provide correct password everything works.

But when I provide wrong password my Android app crashes because `java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests: 21` is thrown.

It looks like my Android client goes to requested url (`inventoryItems/1`) and then it is redirected to `login` page. Then my clients tries to authenticate on that page again, because I have `.addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password))` added to every request (I assume). Login is failed again, so it is redirected again to login page where it sends wrong credentials again and again is redirected...

**My question 1: how to deal with login failed properly on Android and/or Spring?**

**My question 2: how to handle other errors (like bad request) properly on Android and/or Spring?**

What I have tried:

1. Disable followRedirects and followSslRedirects on Android side like this:

   ```
    private fun getHttpClient(user: String, pass: String): OkHttpClient =
        OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .followRedirects(false)
            .followSslRedirects(talse)
            .authenticator(getBasicAuth(user,pass))
            .build()
   ```
2. Add `.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")` header, also on Android side:

   ```
   private fun getBasicAuth(username: String?, password: String?):Authenticator? =
            object : Authenticator {
                override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: okhttp3.Response): Request? {
                  return response
                    .request()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", Credentials.basic(username, password))
                    .addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
                    .build()
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got this (answering my own question). Solution is based on this: [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-authentication-failure-handler)

I will not accept my answer, maybe someone will propose some solution without deprecated class, and maybe with good explanation.

I have created my own `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, like this:

```
class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler : AuthenticationFailureHandler {
    private val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()

    @Throws(IOException::class, ServletException::class)
    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(
        request: HttpServletRequest?,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        exception: AuthenticationException
    ) {
        response.status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()
        val data: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        data["timestamp"] = Calendar.getInstance().time
        data["exception"] = exception.message.toString()
        response.outputStream.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data))
    }
}
```

I had to configure security manually by creating this class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfiguration : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(API_USERNAME)
            .password(passwordEncoder().encode(API_PASSWORD))
            .roles(API_ROLE)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
    }

    @Bean
    fun authenticationFailureHandler(): AuthenticationFailureHandler = CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler()

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    companion object {
        private const val API_USERNAME = "user1"
        private const val API_PASSWORD = "user1"
        private const val API_ROLE = "USER"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class is deprected. I will deal with that later.